# Is it possible to treat git submodule as plain files?

Tags: git

I have a project structure like this:

```
MyProject
- .git
  - ...
- some_files
- MyDirectory
  - .git
    - ...
  - other_files
```

Git repo in `MyProject` is the main repo to commit files to Github.

Git repo in MyDirectory is part of the project and I want to add it's `.git` folder and `other_files` to the main repo directly as regular files.

Is there an easy way to do so?

I tried specifying the files through `git add`, but it returns the error:

`fatal: Pathspec 'MyDirectory/other_files' is in submodule 'MyDirectory'`

Other solutions I found suggested removing `.git` folder which doesn't suit my task.